# Datediff can cause i can't execute my statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

The example data :

Table **Employee**:

```
EMPL_KODE | EMPL_NAME |SEX    |SECTION
001       | Michel    |Male   |HR
002       | Clara     |Female |GA
003       | Rafael    |Male   |HR
```

Table **Attendance**:

```
EMPL_KODE | EMPL_NAME |DATE_IN    |TIME_IN |TIME_OUT
001       | Michel    |25.04.2016 |06:50   |15:40
002       | Clara     |25.04.2016 |06:15   |15:43
003       | Rafael    |25.04.2016 |06:25   |15:45
001       | Michel    |26.04.2016 |06:23   |15:42
002       | Clara     |26.04.2016 |06:10   |15:41
003       | Rafael    |26.04.2016 |06:30   |15:42
001       | Michel    |27.04.2016 |06:33   |15:42
002       | Clara     |27.04.2016 |06:54   |15:44
003       | Rafael    |27.04.2016 |07:00   |15:45
```

From both of those table, I want to :

1. Join the `employee` and `attendance` tables
2. Show total minutes or hours for every `Empl_Kode`

I want the output like this :

```
EMPL_KODE | EMPL_NAME | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT | TOTAL_MINUTES | TOTAL_HOURS
```

SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE, EMPLOYEE.EMPL_NAME,
    CAST(ATTANDANCE.DATE_IN + ATTANDANCE.TIME_IN AS TIMESTAMP) AS   "TIME_IN", 
    CAST(ATTENDANCE.DATE_IN + ATTENDANCE.TIME_OUT AS TIMESTAMP) AS "TIME_OUT", 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ATTENDANCE.TIME_IN, ATTENDANCE.TIME_OUT)) AS "TOTAL_MINUTES",
    SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, ATTENDANCE.TIME_IN, ATTENDANCE.TIME_OUT)) AS "TOTAL_HOURS"
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE
JOIN 
    ATTENDANCE ON EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE = ATTENDANCE.EMPL_KODE
GROUP BY 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE, EMPLOYEE.EMPL_NAME;
```

I get an error message:

> Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

What's wrong with my code ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: The issue is exactly what it states; that you're trying to group by two things and the rest of the select list aren't in aggregate functions or the group by clause... Either you need to include them in an aggregate function (e.g. max, min, sum, etc...) or you need to include them in the GROUP BY...

Comment: If you show us some sample data, you might get a meaningful workaround from somebody.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have show the details into my question. Please help.

Comment: Is it **SQL Server** (from Microsoft), or **Firebird** ?? Please remove the other unnecessary tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE, 
   EMPLOYEE.EMPL_NAME,
   MIN(CAST(ATTANDANCE.DATE_IN + ATTANDANCE.TIME_IN AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "TIME_IN", 
   MAX(CAST(ATTANDANCE.DATE_IN + ATTANDANCE.TIME_OUT AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "TIME_OUT",
   SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ATTANDANCE.TIME_IN,ATTANDANCE.TIME_OUT)) AS "TOTAL_MINUTES",
   SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,ATTANDANCE.TIME_IN,ATTANDANCE.TIME_OUT)) AS "TOTAL_HOURS"
FROM EMPLOYEE
JOIN ATTANDANCE
     ON EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE=ATTANDANCE.EMPL_KODE
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE, EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE;
```

Comment: You are joining on the same column twice, and there is no point in joining to the `Employee` table.

Comment: @Dr. Stitch : brilliant ! the code works on me. thank you !